# List a custom taxonomy's terms, with links, on the taxonomy page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, template-hierarchy

I have registered a custom post type in my functions.php file for "Wines", with this code:

```
function customposttype_wines() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => 'Wines',
    'singular_name'       => 'Wine',
    'menu_name'           => 'Wines',
    'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Wine',
    'all_items'           => 'All Wines',
    'view_item'           => 'View Wine',
    'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Wine',
    'add_new'             => '+',
    'edit_item'           => 'Edit Wine',
    'update_item'         => 'Update Wine',
    'search_items'        => 'Search Wines',
    'not_found'           => 'No Wines found',
    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'No Wines found in Trash',
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'wines',
    'description'         => 'Wine Reviews',
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', ),
    'unset'            => array ('date'),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 
                'wines',
                $args 
                );

}
add_action( 'init', 'customposttype_wines', 0 );
```

And registered 9 custom taxonomies (brand, region, grape, etc.) with this code (repeated 9 times with only the `<XXX>` changing for each):

```
function customtaxonomy_<XXX> ()  {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => '<XXX>',
    'singular_name'              => '<XXX>',
    'menu_name'                  => '<XXX>s',
    'all_items'                  => 'All <XXX>s',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent <XXX>',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent <XXX>:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New <XXX> Name',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New <XXX>',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit <XXX>',
    'update_item'                => 'Update <XXX>',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate <XXX>s w/commas',
    'search_items'               => 'Search <XXX>s',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or Remove <XXX>s',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used <XXX>s',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'query_var'                  => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 
    '<XXX>s',
    'wines',
    $args 
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'customtaxonomy_<XXX>', 0 );
```

Now I am trying to display the lists of custom taxonomy terms on the parent page of each, so when visiting www.mywebsite.com/wines/`<XXX>` there is a list, with links, to all the terms that have been entered.

Right now when I visit www.mywebsite.com/wines/`<XXX>` I just see the 404.php error page. But if I visit a taxonomy term page I see the posts within there fine, ie: www.mywebsite.com/wines/`<XXX>`/term

I tried using a taxonomy template hierarchy page, `taxonomy-<XXX>.php` but it will not load, still just shows the 404.php.

Pulling hair here, any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Just for a moment - Rereading question... you going to show a what? category page of non category? (just for a moment try to remamber a /category or /tags url in any of WordPress sites you ever visit/create)... (i am not talking that this imposible)... its just require a custom solution with rewrite urls/query vars/template filter. Let us know if question still active...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Oleg. I was not able to find a solution to do it the way I wanted/thought I could. I will update the question with my answer for how I did it and mark as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution for doing it the way I was wanting/thinking I could. So...decided to name the **taxonomies** the singular name (ie: brand, grape, region) and then create **pages** with the plural of the same name (ie: brands, grapes, regions) and on each **page** I will have to use the `get_terms` function for a specific **taxonomy** to be able to have links to each term created under each taxonomy. But now I can't get `get_terms` to work. Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

Read more carefully about [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), you will notice that you forgot a rewrite argument, that anables pretty links (rewrites + links generation) for your taxonomy. As for listing taxonomies you can use [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) or any [other](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=list%20terms) alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I did think of that and had read through. The rewrite argument is set to "true" by default and the slug is set to "$taxonomy" by default, so wouldn't I not need to include this if I would just be using those same settings?

Comment: Correct, if not explicitly stated, the rewrite defaults to the taxonomy name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a 404 you might need to re-save your permalinks.

If you want all the taxonomies to display the same and you don't have any other custom taxonomies to worry about you could just work in the `taxonomy.php` template. If you do have other taxonomies you could instruct WP to use the same template for all these taxonomies via the `template_include` filter.

```
function wpa_120317_template_include($template) {
        $taxonomies = array( 'XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ' );
    if ( is_tax( $taxonomies ) ){
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/custom-taxonomy-for-wines.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpa_120317_template_include' );
```

And then on this `custom-taxonomy-for-wines.php` template you could include the following code, which would display a list of links to all the terms in that archive.

```
$obj = get_queried_object();
if( isset($obj->taxonomy)){
    $terms = get_terms( $obj->taxonomy );
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        echo '<ul class="term-list">';
        foreach( $terms as $term ){
            printf( '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>', get_term_link( $term ), esc_attr( __('Link to ') . $term->name ), $term->name );
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have visited the Permalinks settings page and resaved to "flush the rewrite rules" but still the 404.php loads. I implemented your code and it loads the list of the terms BUT on the term links...so if I visit `mywebsite.com/wines/grapes/malbec/` there is a list of all the terms under the grapes taxonomy, including "malbec". I need the list to be one level above, at `mywebsite.com/wines/grapes/`

Comment: If you are *still* getting 404s, I'm stumped and would suggest going into debug-mode... switching to default theme, disabling all plugins, etc. Also check your .htaccess. As far as your other issue, I'm a little unclear what you are saying. WP doesn't create a page at `mywebsite.com/wines/sometaxonomy` so I don't know what to suggest.  Also verify you don't have any pages with the same slugs.